# php echo not displaying while iterating results

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, echo

I have a codeigniter view where "echo" statement is not displaying the output - this happens only from a specific loop that I am giving below. I have tried to run it through a sample for loop with echo statement inside; it works without issues. In the code block below $results is an array returned from the controller. I have tried writing the values of the array to a file and they get written correctly.

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
  fwrite($myfile,$row[0] . PHP_EOL); //this writes perfectly fine
  echo "<tr><td>TEst . $row[0] </td>";  //this doesnt show up
 }
```

i have tried other threads in this forum with subject "echo not working" - they do not match my peculiar case. Any help is appreciated

Comment: try it: echo "<tr><td>TEst ". $row[0]." </td>";

Comment: ist of all print echo "<tr><td>TEst . $row[0] </td>"; **before** fwrite($myfile,$row[0] . PHP_EOL);  maybe it happened due to fwrite();

Comment: print_r($row); inside the loop and check the indexes...

Comment: @Prasad, answers/suggestions provided should work unless your php script is invoked in a way we don't know yet. Can you provide us further details on how you called the script above (i.e, form submission, ajax)? Or can you simply do for loop with a sample echo string? Or how about echo count($results) to check if your results contain something.

Comment: on my page load, there is a ajax call to database to retrieve timesheet for yesterday (by default,yesterday's date). The requirement is to load the rows in a table format in the view. THis is what I am trying to do. While trying to iterate the loop, I find that echo is not displaying but writing to a file works.

Comment: @Prasad: did u checked ?? 
 
print_r($row);?? or print_r($results);

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   foreach ($results as $row) {
     fwrite($myfile,$row[0] . PHP_EOL);
     echo '<tr><td>TEst'.$row[0].'</td></tr>';
 }
```

Comment: Sorry...didnt work. What I found is instead of foreach, if I try numbered loop, I get an error saying  Undefined offset: 0. I am sure, index 0 is available, as proved by fwrite.

Comment: try foreach for key value pair,
foreach($results as $key=>$value){}

Then check values of $key and $value, and according to that make changes.

Comment: I tried:     foreach($results as $key=>$value)
     {
          echo "<tr><td>TEst ".$value[0]."</td>"; //doesnt show up
          fwrite($myfile,$value[0] . PHP_EOL); //works fine
      }

Comment: foreach($results as $key=>$value){
          echo $key."<br>";
          echo $value; 
} 


Run this code and check what it print. It will give you some idea.

Comment: Strange ! it still doesnt echo anything. But, when I try to do a fwrite, it writes the key as 0 and 1 !!

Comment: check   print_r($results); I have a doubt it doesn't contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

WAS:

```
echo "<tr><td>TEst . $row[0] </td>";
```

IS:

```
echo "<tr><td>TEst ".$row[0]."</td>";
```

If that doesn't work, you need to find out what your array really has in it, because it means there is no 0 key. Try,

```
print_r($row);
```

Comment: I thought, that this dot could be an issue - unfortunately, even if I include it, it didnt work. additionally, I found that when I try to access the array by index 0, it throws an error !

Comment: print_r $row; or print_r($row);??

Comment: its little wiered ! print_r also doesnt show up anything. I am sure, the array has data as proved by fwrite statements !

Comment: well if   print_r (...);  doesn't reveal anything then the variable ain't no array

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($results){
foreach ($results as $row) {
  fwrite($myfile,$row[0] . PHP_EOL);

//try this
 echo "<tr><td>TEst ".$row[0]."</td></tr>";

//or this
echo "<tr><td>TEst ".$row->keyname."</td></tr>";

//or this
echo "<tr><td>TEst ".$row['keyname']."</td></tr>";   
 }
}
else
{
echo "NO RESULTS";
}
```